# Access table cell with javascript in chrome console

Tags: javascript, html

I have this table and I want to access the prod_sku value and define it as a variable:

```
<tr class="border first last" id="order-item-row-386470">
<td><h3 class="product-name">prod_name</h3>
</td>
<td data-rwd-label="SKU">prod_sku</td>
<td class="a-right" data-rwd-label="Preço">
    <span class="price-excl-tax">
    <span class="cart-price">

        <span class="price">prod_price</span>                    
    </span>


    </span>
    <br>
</td>
</tr>
```

I get this table with this line:

```
data = document.getElementsByClassName("odd")[0].innerHTML;
```

From this tbody

```
<tbody class="odd">
<tr class="border first last" id="order-item-row-386470">
<td><h3 class="product-name">prod_name</h3>
</td>
<td data-rwd-label="SKU">prod_sku</td>
<td class="a-right" data-rwd-label="Preço">
<span class="price-excl-tax">
<span class="cart-price">
<span class="price">prod_price</span>                    
</span>


</span>
<br>
</td>
<td class="a-right" data-rwd-label="Qtd">
<span class="nobr">
Solicitado: <strong>1</strong><br>
</span>
</td>
<td class="a-right last" data-rwd-label="Subtotal">
<span class="price-excl-tax">
<span class="cart-price">

<span class="price">prod_price</span>                    
</span>


</span>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I access prod_sku?

Comment: From the above structure you would have to target based on an `nth` <td> element. You have no reference to class `odd` in your example. Could you please update your question to include the full table?

Comment: the class odd is in the tbody actually. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query selector to match the `data-rwd-label` attribute.

```
document.querySelector('td[data-rwd-label=SKU]').innerHTML
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to support stone age browsers, then you can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to grab your `td` based on `data attribute`. If you have to support a myriad of outdated browsers and you need to d a lot of these types of lookups, then jquery is quite good at it.

Comment: How could I use query selector in my case? I tried this: document.querySelector("odd.SKU"); but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = document.querySelector('td[data-rwd-label="SKU"]').innerHTML;
```

But would be more interesting to improve the html structure of your table.